# How Do You Display an Image if a Condition is True?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get an image in pygame to display after a collision is detected. But the problem I'm having is that the image only displays when the IF condition is true. Is there any way that I can get the image to stay if the condition is only true once?

Syntax /

```
#Game Over
if collision == True:
    SCREEN.blit(start_menu, (0, 0))
    SCREEN.blit(final_score, (800, 5))
```

NOTE: I already have a while statement and a for loop running under this program

Comment: Why not set a separate flag to true once the image is shown, and then check for that and not show it at the next collision?

Comment: I tried that and it just displays the image without there even being a collision detected.

Comment: `if collision == True and image_shown == False: show image, set image_shown = True`

Comment: `if collision == True and SCREEN.blit(game_over, (0, 0)) == False:
        SCREEN.blit(game_over, (0, 0))
        SCREEN.blit(game_over, (0, 0)) == True`

"Like this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

1. Make a variable:

   ```
   GameOver = False
   ```
2. Use the if statement you use to detect collision

   ```
   if collision == True:
       GameOver = True
   ```
3. Display your blit with this variable

   ```
   if GameOver == True:
       SCREEN.blit(start_menu, (0, 0))
       SCREEN.blit(final_score, (800, 5))
   ```

Please tell me if this helped!

Comment: You need to add an equal sign in the third if-statement. Also, variable names should use lowercase only, not CamelCase. CamelCase is for class names. It's often common to not check equality with a boolean and just do `if collision: game_over = True`

Comment: Ah, I see I've made a mistake! Tanks for letting me know!